# Multiple redux instances for multiple react apps on a single web page

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am building an embedded widget using React and Redux. so people can take a snippet code and run it in their website

one case that i need to support is having multiple widgets on the same web page. in other words, having multiple app instances with different config for each instance.

the embedded code will look something like:

```
<script src="https://widget.sample.network/v1"></script>
<script>
new ConvertWidget({
    "type": "1",
    "baseCurrencyId": "594bb7e468a95e00203b048d",
    "pairCurrencyId": "5937d635231e97001f744267",
    "primaryColor": "#102644",
    "displayCurrency": "ETH"
}, document.querySelector('.sample1'));
</script>
```

so as you can see I can render the React app into the provided element, so in that case we have multiple React instances on a page.

my question, is how to deal with Redux? I couldn't find any info of how to create multiple Redux instances, and connect each instance to his React pair. is it possible? if not what other alternative I have?

Comment: Redux revolves around its store. It's up to you to create a store for each widget, or to share it. Am I right in assuming `ConvertWidget` calls ReactDOM.render? In that case each widget can declare its own <Provider/> and you can create a unique store for each one (if that's what you need)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. you right, I do use ReactDOM.render, but I dont have <Provider /> component since I do not use react-redux library

Comment: What do you use to update your components when redux state changes? In any case, wherever you use a redux store, you should simply create multiple of them, one for each widget.

Comment: Actually it was really easy,


const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const ebableReduxDevTools = window.devToolsExtension && config.getEnv() == 'development'; 
const createStoreFinal = compose(ebableReduxDevTools ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f)(createStore);
const store = createStoreFinal(rootReducer);

this code will create a store instance, so as you said I am creating a new instance for each widget.

 Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome!